# Why is my 2D interpolant generating a matrix with swapped axes in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, ipython

I solve a differential equation with vector inputs

**y' = f(t,y), y(t_0) = y_0**

where **y0 = y(x)**

using the explicit Euler method, which says that

**y_(i+1) = y_i + h*f(t_i, y_i)**

where **t** is a time vector, **h** is the step size, and **f** is the right-hand side of the differential equation.

The python code for the method looks like this:

```
for i in np.arange(0,n-1):
        y[i+1,...] = y[i,...] + dt*myode(t[i],y[i,...])
```

The result is a **k,m** matrix **y**, where **k** is the size of the **t** dimension, and **m** is the size of **y**.

The vectors **y** and **t** are returned.

**t**, **x**, and **y** are passed to `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(t, x, y, kx=1, ky=1)`:

```
g = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(t, x, y, kx=1, ky=1)
```

The resulting object `g` takes new vectors `ti,xi ( g(p,q) )` to give `y_int`, which is **y** interpolated at the points defined by **ti** and **xi**.

Here is my problem:

- The documentation for RectBivariateSpline describes the `__call__` method in terms of x and y:
  `__call__(x, y[, mth])` *Evaluate spline at the grid points defined by the coordinate arrays*
- The matplotlib documentation for plot_surface uses similar notation:
  `Axes3D.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)`
  with the important difference that X and Y are 2D arrays which are generated by `numpy.meshgrid()`.

When I compute simple examples, the input order is the same in both and the result is exactly what I would expect. In my explicit Euler example, however, the initial order is `ti,xi`, yet the surface plot of the interpolant output only makes sense if I reverse the order of the inputs, like so:

```
ax2.plot_surface(xi, ti, u, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

While I am glad that it works, I'm not satisfied because **I cannot explain why**, nor why (apart from the array geometry) it is necessary to swap the inputs. Ideally, I would like to restructure the code so that the input order is consistent.

Here is a working code example to illustrate what I mean:

```
# Heat equation example with explicit Euler method
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplot
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.interpolate as interp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pdb

# explicit Euler method
def eev(myode,tspan,y0,dt):
    # Preprocessing
    # Time steps
    tspan[1] = tspan[1] + dt
    t = np.arange(tspan[0],tspan[1],dt,dtype=float)
    n = t.size
    m = y0.shape[0]
    y = np.zeros((n,m),dtype=float)
    y[0,:] = y0

    # explicit Euler recurrence relation
    for i in np.arange(0,n-1):
        y[i+1,...] = y[i,...] + dt*myode(t[i],y[i,...])

    return y,t

# generate matrix A
# u'(t) = A*u(t) + g*u(t)
def a_matrix(n):
    aa = sp.diags([1, -2, 1],[-1,0,1],(n,n))
    return aa

# System of ODEs with finite differences
def f(t,u):
    dydt = np.divide(1,h**2)*A.dot(u)
    return dydt

# homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions
def rbd(t):
    ul = np.zeros((t,1))
    return ul

# Initial value problem -----------

def main():
    # Metal rod 
    # spatial discretization
    # number of inner nodes
    m = 20
    x0 = 0
    xn = 1
    x = np.linspace(x0,xn,m+2)
    # Step size
    global h
    h = x[1]-x[0]

    # Initial values
    u0 = np.sin(np.pi*x)

    # A matrix
    global A
    A = a_matrix(m)

    # Time
    t0 = 0
    tend = 0.2
    # Time step width
    dt = 0.0001
    tspan = [t0,tend]

    # Test r for stability
    r = np.divide(dt,h**2)
    if r <= 0.5:
        u,t = eev(f,tspan,u0[1:-1],dt)      
    else:
        print('r = ',r)
        print('r > 0.5. Explicit Euler method will not be stable.')

    # Add boundary values back
    rb = rbd(t.size)
    u = np.hstack((rb,u,rb))

    # Interpolate heat values
    # Create interpolant. Note the parameter order
    fi = interp.RectBivariateSpline(t, x, u, kx=1, ky=1)

    # Create vectors for interpolant
    xi = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],100)
    ti = np.linspace(t0,tend,100)

    # Compute function values from interpolant
    u_int = fi(ti,xi)

    # Change xi, ti in to 2D arrays
    xi,ti = np.meshgrid(xi,ti)

    # Create figure and axes objects
    fig3 = mplot.figure(1)
    ax3 = fig3.gca(projection='3d')
    print('xi.shape =',xi.shape,'ti.shape =',ti.shape,'u_int.shape =',u_int.shape)

    # Plot surface. Note the parameter order, compare with interpolant!
    ax3.plot_surface(xi, ti, u_int, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
    ax3.set_xlabel('xi')
    ax3.set_ylabel('ti')

main()
mplot.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see you define :

```
# Change xi, ti in to 2D arrays
    xi,ti = np.meshgrid(xi,ti)
```

Change this to :

```
ti,xi = np.meshgrid(ti,xi)
```

and

```
ax3.plot_surface(xi, ti, u_int, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

to

```
ax3.plot_surface(ti, xi, u_int, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

and it works fine (if I understood well ).

Comment: Excellent, you did indeed understand well. Your solution worked.

Comment: @Stephen: I don't understand why George's solution works for you (at least it doesn't fix the problem for me). While it's not documented in an obvious way, the behavior you noticed was actually introduced on purpose (more or less), see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3164 . Long story short, `meshgrid(x, y)` follows the convention of making the y-direction the first dimension and the x-direction the second, while the rest of numpy (`RectBivariateSpline` for instance) doesn't.

Comment: @balu Thanks. (It's possible that I made other changes to my code that ended up making George's changes work; it's been some time since I looked at this.) While this may be intended behaviour, it isn't properly documented (wouldn't you expect the doc entry for `RectBivariateSpline` to mention axis ordering?), so it is a major cause of confusion.

Comment: @Stephen: Yep, I agree.